# Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}\text dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

The standard operating procedure for such questions is substituting $x$ with $\frac 1t$

So
$$\int \frac{-t}{(t^2+1)\sqrt {t^2-1}} \text dt$$

Which gives more or less the same expression. How do I solve this question?

Comment: Note that in the denominator you have the term $\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$, so you should use first a trigonometric substitution. Please, read my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there !

we have $$\int \frac{-t}{(t^2+1)(\sqrt {t^2-1})} dt$$
let $t^2=u$ :then we have $$\int \frac{-du}{2(u+1)\sqrt{(u-1)}}$$  Now take $\sqrt{u-1}=y$ we have $$\int \frac{-dy}{y^2+2}$$ which should be easy

Comment: The only problem is that the substitution in the post was done incorrectly, so this solution doesn't apply

Comment: @NinadMunshi it was a typo, I fixed it now

Comment: @Aditya fixed!!

Answer (score 4):

Let $x=\sin(t)$, so $dx=\cos(t)dt$. Then $\sqrt{1-x^{2}}=\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}(t)}=\cos(t)$ and $t=\arcsin(x)$, so we can see that $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}(x^{2}+1)}dx=\int \frac{1}{\sin^{2}(t)+1}dt=\int \frac{1}{\sin^{2}(t)+1}\left(\frac{\csc^{2}(t)}{\csc^{2}(t)}\right)dt$$
now, let $s=\cot(t)$ then $ds=-\csc^{2}(t)$. Therefore, $$\int \frac{1}{\sin^{2}(t)+1}\left(\frac{\csc^{2}(t)}{\csc^{2}(t)}\right)dt=\int-\frac{1}{s^{2}+2}ds=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan \left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+c$$
So, we have $$\boxed{\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}(x^{2}+1)}dx =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} \right)+c}$$

Comment: i would say $\sqrt{1-\sin^2 t}=|\cos t|$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore it doesn't matter. Since the integrand has $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ the domain is implied to be a subset of $(-1,1)$, which means you can choose the domain of $t$ to be the appropriate subset of $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. $\cos t$ is always positive there.

Comment: That’s a very odd trigonometric substitution. I mean it’s correct, but I haven’t seen that one before.